# Push in array only values ​that contain a certain string

Tags: javascript

I would like only data containing a certain string to be sent from my array to another array
for example

```
test=something
test1=something
test=testsadsad
```

If my array contains `test=`
My new array will be ['something', 'testsadsad']
This is my code.

```
let data = Object.values(args);
        let serializedData = data.join("\n");
        let newArray = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].includes("test=") === true) {
                console.log(data[i])
                newArray.push(data[i].split("test="));
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should use filter method on your array.

Comment: What error are you getting?  What bad behavior?  If I had to guess, it would be around the fact that "split" returns an array of the strings as delimited by the parameter that you pass it.  And I think you're trying to just get the remaining string.  You could split on "=" and then take the second item in the resulting array.

Comment: newArray.push(data[i].split("test=")); should be newArray.push(data[i].replace("test=", ''));

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your logic like this

```js
//simulated data
const data = [
  "test=something",
  "test1=something",
  "test=testsadsad",
]

let newArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  //`key` is `test` and `value` is `something`
  const [key, value] = data[i].split("=") //splitted by `=`
  if (key === "test") {
    newArray.push(value);
  }
}

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not formatting the data correctly when pushing onto the array.

```
let data = Object.values(args);
let newArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].includes("test=") === true) {
        console.log(data[i])
        // Note It looks like your problem is here
        newArray.push(data[i].replace("test=", ''));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input array is `data` then this will return the desired output:

```js
let output = data
    .filter(item => item.includes("test="))
    .map(item => item.split("test=")[1])
```

This filters the array by selecting all items that include `test=` and then maps each result to the substring after `test=`.